# Return image content from controller to view MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want a controller to serve a chart control and use that in View directly . What i did is in Razor i used

```
<p>
    <img src="/Exam/ChartReport" />
</p>
```

and in Controller i created an action method like

```
public ActionResult ChartReport()
{
    var data = new System.Collections.ArrayList
               {
                   new { X = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2), Y = 200 },
                   new { X = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), Y = 300 },
                   new { X = DateTime.Now, Y = 500 }
               };
    new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(400, 200, System.Web.Helpers.ChartTheme.Blue)
        .AddTitle("Price enquiries")
        .DataBindTable(data, "X")
        .Write("png");
    return null;
}
```

Now what i want is to pass the model as it is from View to the Controller action as parameter , so  i can create chart without making any Db queries . How can i do this . My View is created based on model

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.SampleModel
<p>
   <img src="/Exam/ChartReport" />
</p>
```

I tried to do

```
<p>
    < img src="/Exam/ChartReport/@Model" />
</p>
```

and in controller

```
public ActionResult ChartReport(SampleModel model) //But model is null
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to your controller action as follows:

```
<img ... src="/Exam/ChartReport?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2" />
```

And your action should be as follows:

```
public class ExamController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ChartReport(string parameter1, string parameter2)
    {
         ...
         // Return the contents of the Stream to the client
         return File(imgStream, "image/png");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, you might want to add that the `src` link should be composed with one of the `Url.Action` methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.108).aspx). Just in case the application is not running at server root.

Comment: I can add parameters one by one , right but what i want is the entire Model data as it is . ( The model contains List of Results and if i can pass the model as it is to controller i can create the chart from  the available filled List of Result data.) . So passing one by one is not an option for me